# How to prevent a style sheet in qgroupbox from being applied to the buttons inside?

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I'm writing a application using Qt. Make a clean program and Only added a groupbox and two push buttons.

The only line of code I added is this:

ui->groupBox->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(/home/ariela/test.png)");

The problem is that the background of the push buttons also shows the section the image. I want them to look like normal (default gray) and I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a selector:

```
ui->groupBox->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox{background-image: url(/home/ariela/test.png);}");
```

More about styelsheets [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html).

Comment: Thank you!!! I was trying to do the complicated thing and use the selector for the pushbuttons!!!